# HFM Client Failing To Connect To FTP

Tags: ftp, mysql, folding-at-home

I have setup a proftpd with virtual users using MySQL. I am able to log in with Filezilla and WinSCP just fine. I am also able to upload, delete and edit.

The issue that I am facing, is when using HFM.NET to connect via FTP, I get an error stating it can't find a file or no access.

[HFM FTP Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfUrf.png)

[HFM 550 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPYHj.png)

```
Test Connection Failed
The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
```

However when it does do the test connection, the proftpd log shows it successfully logged in.

```
2017-03-15 21:50:50,981 xxxx proftpd[17210] localhost (xxxx[xxxx]): FTP session opened.
2017-03-15 21:50:52,472 xxxx proftpd[17210] localhost (xxxx[xxxx]): USER simmons: Login successful.
2017-03-15 21:50:52,546 xxxx proftpd[17210] localhost (xxxx[xxxx]): FTP session closed.
```

The users home folder is set to /home/simmons

Ownership is ftpuser:ftpgroup

Modification is 755

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 ftpuser ftpgroup 4.0K Mar 15 21:51 simmons
```

Comment: Show more of the settings from the HFM app like `Startup and External` and `Options`.

Comment: THanks for the comment @MagicallyDelicous. Was able to resolve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to troubleshoot this some more. I didn't realize that setting the FTP server to create home directories meant it was their root. So I set the path in HFM to just / and fixed the issue.